# Reset the localstorage value when moved / redirected to another page and if the browser closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery tab in one of my page, I want it to store tab value if only if I'm on that page, But when moved to another page source or redirected to page with no tab that value to be cleared and reset, And when browser closed that localStorage value to be cleared. So if I came back to that page again the value will be set only if the tab link have been clicked.

Thanks.

//jquery

```
    function myTab(){
        var last_id = localStorage.getItem('tab_id');
        if (last_id) {
            $('ul.tab li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
            $(".tab li").eq(Number(last_id.match(/\d+/)[0])-1).addClass('current');
            $("#" + last_id).addClass('current');
        }
        $('ul.tab li').click(function() {
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
            $('ul.tab li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
            localStorage.setItem('tab_id', tab_id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use local storage, instead store the value in a variable. The variable will only exist in the context of the page where it is instantiated.

Comment: But if I could store in a variable and the page refreshed the current value will not be the one clicked thus why I used a localStorage to make it stick to the tab if page refreshed. Help me please

Comment: Look into the History API, you can manipulate the browser history to store a reference to the active tab. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API